# Click & drag with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad, xdotool, xbindkeys

The "click down" key on my laptop touchpad requires too much force, making it difficult to click & drag. I would like to solve this by holding down a keyboard shortcut while dragging along the touchpad to click & drag, then release the shortcut to finish.

I attempted to do this using xdotool. Where "xdotool mousedown 1" would execute when I press down the shortcut and "xdotool mouseup 1" executes when I release the keys. However I could not figure out how to create a shortcut for releasing keys with native Ubuntu.

Next, I attempted to do this with xbindkeys, using the config:

```
"xdotool mousedown 1"
m:0x104 + c:37
Control + Control_L 

"xdotool mouseup 1"
Release + m:0x104 + c:37
Release + Control + Control_L
```

but instead it executes mousedown upon releasing the keys, and the "Release" command appears to do nothing, never triggering mouseup.